# Sorting of photos, on ipad

Tags: ipad, photos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPad organizing photos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9135/ipad-organizing-photos)

What is the criterion for sorting photos, are used by iTunes, when you are uploading them to iPad?

I'm just trying to arrange photos in right order, before uploading to iPad, but without success, they are still unordered, when i open this album on ipad :(

I've

- renamed all photos as "0001.jpg", "0002.jpg", etc
- removed all EXIF information from this files
- set identical creation and modification time

it helps in most cases, but not always :( what i'm doing wrong? 
I don't believe that it can't do such basic things as a ordering of photos in photo album.

Maybe there exists are an tool for that? ideally an app for ipad.

Answer (score 0):

For photo organization, you can't go wrong with Sort Shots. It brings the power of tagging to your photo collection; once you get everything set up you'll be able to find exactly what you're looking for in just a couple of taps. I highly recommend this app to anyone trying to get their photos organized.