# Can I use my iPad to organize photos that are stored externally? 

Tags: ipad, photos, aperture

I would like to organize my photos with iPad (remove, edit, create albums etc).

I have the synology NAS and I can run the Photo app on the NAS (server) and I can use the DS Photo+ app on iPad (client) but this app can be used only as a viewer (I can't organize photos).

I also have the Aperture on the Mac and I can use the iTunes to sync the photos to the iPad but it is the same problem as with the NAS. I can't delete the photos or organize them in any way - it is only a viewer.

I have around 100k photos and I have to keep them externally. Thus, I have to use the iPad only as a remote viewer (client). I don't want to use any web related service for that like flickr, picasa etc.
It is not a problem for me to download photos from the camera to the iPad and then organize them and finally move them to the NAS.

Any ideas how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Cinq Photo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cinq-photo/id405485030?mt=8)? Not sure it has everything you are looking for but thought it might be a good start

Answer (score 1):

Pixelsync offers rating and flagging of your Aperture library on the iPad:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pixelsync/id409409239?mt=8

It has some bugs but it looks such a promising app though.

Comment: It hangs when the photo library is stored on remote nas.

Comment: You may contact the [developer directly](http://www.pixelsyncapp.com/contact) then..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not do this.. the only possibility to use some remote client like flickr or even dropbox.